# ¿Cómo acceder a datos de un array dentro de un array con interpolación ANGULAR?

Tags: angular, json, interpolacion

Hola comunidad espero que estén bien. Tengo un problema con acceder a datos ya que realmente no se cómo acceder con interpolación a este tipo de estructuras.

Ejemplo:

```
objeto = {
  "_id":ObjectId("aidsidasai24"),
  "nombre":"Juan",
  "dirección":[{"calle":"falsa"},{"interior":123}] //A este en especifico
}
```

Tengo este conjunto de datos que ya los recibí pero al momento de querer acceder a ellos no encuentro la manera de sacar sus datos individualmente puedo sacar el array, pero no individualmente. De este JSON quiero sacar el **nombreEspecialidad** pero ni idea.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quise acceder con esta forma pero como les comente solamente obtengo este resultado y no lo que se ve en la imagen de arriba que es el dato del **nombreEspecialidad**.

Codigo:

```
<div class="card g-4 mt-5" *ngFor="let medico of listaMedico2">
                    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/male-face-silhouette-or-icon-man-avatar-profile-unknown-or-anonymous-vector-id1087531642?k=20&m=1087531642&s=612x612&w=0&h=D6OBNUY7ZxQTAHNVtL9mm2wbHb_dP6ogIsCCWCqiYQg=" class="card-img-top" height="150" width="150">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" style="color: black;">{{medico.nombreMedico}} {{medico.apellidoPatMedico}} {{medico.apellidoMatMedico}}</h5> <!--NOMBRE DEL MEDICO-->
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"> <!--Todas la información del médico estara aqui-->
                        <li class="list-group-item">Especialidades</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">{{medico.especialidad}}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="card-link" [routerLink]="['/generarCita',medico._id]">Agendar Cita</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna sugerencia?, se los agradecería mucho, gracias por leer esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar otro `ngFor`

```
 <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let m of medico.especialidad">{{m.nombreEspecialidad}}</li>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo resolvi también cambiando el tipo de dato de la estructura con un "nombreVariable = any[] = []" donde guardo la variable. Y ahora así referenciar el json con esto.